# Using JSON Patch to add values to a dictionary

Tags: c#, json-patch

### Overview

I'm trying to write a web service using ASP.NET Core that allows clients to query and modify the state of a microcontroller. This microcontroller contains a number of systems that I model within my application - for instance, a PWM system, an actuator input system, etc.

The components of these systems all have particular *properties* that can be queried or modified using a [JSON patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) request. For example, the 4th PWM on the micro can be enabled using an HTTP request carrying `{"op":"replace", "path":"/pwms/3/enabled", "value":true}`. To support this, I'm using the [`AspNetCore.JsonPatch`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch/) library.

**My problem** is that I'm trying to implement JSON Patch support for a new "CAN database" system that logically should map a definition name to a particular CAN message definition, and I'm not sure how to go about this.

### Details

The diagram below models the CAN database system. A `CanDatabase` instance should logically contain a dictionary of the form `IDictionary<string, CanMessageDefinition>`.

[image: CAN Database system model]

To support creating new message definitions, my application should allow users to send JSON patch requests like this:

```json
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/candb/my_new_definition",
    "value": {
        "template": ["...", "..."],
        "repeatRate": "...",
        "...": "...",
    }
}
```

Here, `my_new_definition` would define the definition **name**, and the object associated with `value` should be deserialised to a `CanMessageDefinition` **object**. This should then be stored as a new key-value pair in the `CanDatabase` dictionary.

The issue is that `path` should specify a **property path** which for statically-typed objects would be...well, static (an exception to this is that it allows for referencing *array elements* e.g. `/pwms/3` as above).

### What I've tried

**A. The Leeroy Jenkins approach**

Forget the fact that I *know* it won't work - I tried the implementation below (which uses static-typing only despite the fact I need to support dynamic JSON Patch paths) just to see what happens.

**Implementation**

```c#
internal sealed class CanDatabaseModel : DeviceComponentModel<CanDatabaseModel>
{
    public CanDatabaseModel()
    {
        this.Definitions = new Dictionary<string, CanMessageDefinition>();
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "candb")]
    public IDictionary<string, CanMessageDefinition> Definitions { get; }

    ...
}
```

**Test**

```json
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/candb/foo",
    "value": {
        "messageId": 171,
        "template": [17, 34],
        "repeatRate": 100,
        "canPort": 0
    }
}
```

**Outcome**

An `InvalidCastException` is thrown at the site where I try to apply the specified changes to the `JsonPatchDocument`.

Site:

```cs
var currentModelSnapshot = this.currentModelFilter(this.currentModel.Copy());
var snapshotWithChangesApplied = currentModelSnapshot.Copy();
diffDocument.ApplyTo(snapshotWithChangesApplied);
```

Exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonDictionaryContract' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract'.
```

---

**B. Relying on dynamic JSON Patching**

A more promising plan of attack seemed to be relying on [dynamic JSON patching](https://github.com/KevinDockx/JsonPatch.Dynamic), which involves performing patch operations on instances of `ExpandoObject`. This allows you to use JSON patch documents to add, remove or replace properties since you're dealing with a dynamically-typed object.

**Implementation**

```c#
internal sealed class CanDatabaseModel : DeviceComponentModel<CanDatabaseModel>
{
    public CanDatabaseModel()
    {
        this.Definitions = new ExpandoObject();
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "candb")]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Definitions { get; }

    ...
}
```

**Test**

```json
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/candb/foo",
    "value": {
        "messageId": 171,
        "template": [17, 34],
        "repeatRate": 100,
        "canPort": 0
    }
}
```

**Outcome**

Making this change allows this part of my test to run without exceptions being raised, but JSON Patch has no knowledge of what to deserialise `value` as, resulting in the data being stored in the dictionary as a `JObject` rather than a `CanMessageDefinition`:

[image: Outcome of attempt B]

Would it be possible to 'tell' JSON Patch how to deserialise the information by any chance? Perhaps something along the lines of using a `JsonConverter` attribute on `Definitions`?

```c#
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "candb")]
[JsonConverter(...)]
public IDictionary<string, object> Definitions { get; }
```

---

### Summary

- I need to support JSON patch requests that add values to a dictionary
- I've tried going down the purely-static route, which failed
- I've tried using dynamic JSON patching

  - This partly worked, but my data was stored as a `JObject` type instead of the intended type
  - Is there an attribute (or some other technique) I can apply to my property to let it deserialise to the correct type (not an anonymous type)?

Comment: Implementing a custom JSON deserializer looks like a viable solution. Could you give more details on `template` in `value` object? Can we move `messageId` and `template` to parent object?

Comment: @Ankit `template` represents a CAN message payload (0-8 bytes), so it would be an array of integers. `messageId` and `template` have to remain as they are because requests need to adhere to the JSON Patch schema as described in [RFC 6902](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902)

Comment: Did you figure out an approach? This is an interesting scenario and I have bookmarked this to work on when I get some time from work.

Comment: @Ankit Not yet. I'm using a temporary workaround (registering a `PropertyChanged` event handler to the `ExpandoObject` to manually convert the new `JObject` into a `CanMessageDefinition`).

Comment: Leeeeroooooooy! :)

Comment: I don't think you can deserialize `IDictionary<T, K>`. Did you try just using `Dictionary<T, K>`? I'm using that and not having any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be any official way to do it, I've come up with a Temporary Solution™ (read: a solution that works well enough so I'll probably keep it forever).

In order to make it seem like JSON Patch handles dictionary-like operations, I created a class called `DynamicDeserialisationStore` which inherits from [`DynamicObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and makes use of JSON Patch's support for dynamic objects.

More specifically, this class overrides methods like `TrySetMember`, `TrySetIndex`, `TryGetMember`, etc. to essentially act like a dictionary, except that it delegates all these operations to callbacks provided to its constructor.

**Implementation**

The code below provides the implementation of `DynamicDeserialisationStore`. It implements `IDictionary<string, object>` (which is the signature JSON Patch requires to work with dynamic objects) but I only implement the bare minimum of the methods I require.

The problem with JSON Patch's support for dynamic objects is that it will set properties to `JObject` instances i.e. it won't automatically perform deserialisation like it would when setting static properties, as it can't infer the type. `DynamicDeserialisationStore` is parameterised on the type of object that it will try to automatically try to deserialise these `JObject` instances to when they're set.

The class accepts callbacks to handle basic dictionary operations instead of maintaining an internal dictionary itself, because in my "real" system model code I don't actually use a dictionary (for various reasons) - I just make it appear that way to clients.

```
internal sealed class DynamicDeserialisationStore<T> : DynamicObject, IDictionary<string, object> where T : class
{
    private readonly Action<string, T> storeValue;
    private readonly Func<string, bool> removeValue;
    private readonly Func<string, T> retrieveValue;
    private readonly Func<IEnumerable<string>> retrieveKeys;

    public DynamicDeserialisationStore(
        Action<string, T> storeValue,
        Func<string, bool> removeValue,
        Func<string, T> retrieveValue,
        Func<IEnumerable<string>> retrieveKeys)
    {
        this.storeValue = storeValue;
        this.removeValue = removeValue;
        this.retrieveValue = retrieveValue;
        this.retrieveKeys = retrieveKeys;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.retrieveKeys().Count();
        }
    }

    private IReadOnlyDictionary<string, T> AsDict
    {
        get
        {
            return (from key in this.retrieveKeys()
                    let value = this.retrieveValue(key)
                    select new { key, value })
                    .ToDictionary(it => it.key, it => it.value);
        }
    }

    public override bool TrySetIndex(SetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, object value)
    {
        if (indexes.Length == 1 && indexes[0] is string && value is JObject)
        {
            return this.TryUpdateValue(indexes[0] as string, value);
        }

        return base.TrySetIndex(binder, indexes, value);
    }

    public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
    {
        if (indexes.Length == 1 && indexes[0] is string)
        {
            try
            {
                result = this.retrieveValue(indexes[0] as string);
                return true;
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                // Pass through.
            }
        }

        return base.TryGetIndex(binder, indexes, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        return this.TryUpdateValue(binder.Name, value);
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        try
        {
            result = this.retrieveValue(binder.Name);
            return true;
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
        }
    }

    private bool TryUpdateValue(string name, object value)
    {
        JObject jObject = value as JObject;
        T tObject = value as T;

        if (jObject != null)
        {
            this.storeValue(name, jObject.ToObject<T>());
            return true;
        }
        else if (tObject != null)
        {
            this.storeValue(name, tObject);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    object IDictionary<string, object>.this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.retrieveValue(key);
        }

        set
        {
            this.TryUpdateValue(key, value);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.AsDict.ToDictionary(it => it.Key, it => it.Value as object).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        this.TryUpdateValue(key, value);
    }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        return this.removeValue(key);
    }

    #region Unused methods
    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    ICollection<string> IDictionary<string, object>.Keys
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    ICollection<object> IDictionary<string, object>.Values
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool IDictionary<string, object>.ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool IDictionary<string, object>.TryGetValue(string key, out object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Tests**

The tests for this class are provided below. I create a mock system model (see image) and perform various JSON Patch operations on it.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
public class DynamicDeserialisationStoreTests
{
    private readonly FooSystemModel fooSystem;

    public DynamicDeserialisationStoreTests()
    {
        this.fooSystem = new FooSystemModel();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Store_Should_Handle_Adding_Keyed_Model()
    {
        // GIVEN the foo system currently contains no foos.
        this.fooSystem.Foos.ShouldBeEmpty();

        // GIVEN a patch document to store a foo called "test".
        var request = "{\"op\":\"add\",\"path\":\"/foos/test\",\"value\":{\"number\":3,\"bazzed\":true}}";
        var operation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Operation<FooSystemModel>>(request);
        var patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument<FooSystemModel>(
            new[] { operation }.ToList(),
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

        // WHEN we apply this patch document to the foo system model.
        patchDocument.ApplyTo(this.fooSystem);

        // THEN the system model should now contain a new foo called "test" with the expected properties.
        this.fooSystem.Foos.ShouldHaveSingleItem();
        FooModel foo = this.fooSystem.Foos["test"] as FooModel;
        foo.Number.ShouldBe(3);
        foo.IsBazzed.ShouldBeTrue();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Store_Should_Handle_Removing_Keyed_Model()
    {
        // GIVEN the foo system currently contains a foo.
        var testFoo = new FooModel { Number = 3, IsBazzed = true };
        this.fooSystem.Foos["test"] = testFoo;

        // GIVEN a patch document to remove a foo called "test".
        var request = "{\"op\":\"remove\",\"path\":\"/foos/test\"}";
        var operation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Operation<FooSystemModel>>(request);
        var patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument<FooSystemModel>(
            new[] { operation }.ToList(),
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

        // WHEN we apply this patch document to the foo system model.
        patchDocument.ApplyTo(this.fooSystem);

        // THEN the system model should be empty.
        this.fooSystem.Foos.ShouldBeEmpty();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Store_Should_Handle_Modifying_Keyed_Model()
    {
        // GIVEN the foo system currently contains a foo.
        var originalFoo = new FooModel { Number = 3, IsBazzed = true };
        this.fooSystem.Foos["test"] = originalFoo;

        // GIVEN a patch document to modify a foo called "test".
        var request = "{\"op\":\"replace\",\"path\":\"/foos/test\", \"value\":{\"number\":6,\"bazzed\":false}}";
        var operation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Operation<FooSystemModel>>(request);
        var patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument<FooSystemModel>(
            new[] { operation }.ToList(),
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

        // WHEN we apply this patch document to the foo system model.
        patchDocument.ApplyTo(this.fooSystem);

        // THEN the system model should contain a modified "test" foo.
        this.fooSystem.Foos.ShouldHaveSingleItem();
        FooModel foo = this.fooSystem.Foos["test"] as FooModel;
        foo.Number.ShouldBe(6);
        foo.IsBazzed.ShouldBeFalse();
    }

    #region Mock Models
    private class FooModel
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "number")]
        public int Number { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bazzed")]
        public bool IsBazzed { get; set; }
    }

    private class FooSystemModel
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, FooModel> foos;

        public FooSystemModel()
        {
            this.foos = new Dictionary<string, FooModel>();
            this.Foos = new DynamicDeserialisationStore<FooModel>(
                storeValue: (name, foo) => this.foos[name] = foo,
                removeValue: name => this.foos.Remove(name),
                retrieveValue: name => this.foos[name],
                retrieveKeys: () => this.foos.Keys);
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "foos")]
        public IDictionary<string, object> Foos { get; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, for instance, deserialize your received Json into an object:

```
var dataDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

And iterate over it, casting and converting the values of the KeyValuePairs you want to patch into your destination type, CanMessageDefinition:

```
Dictionary<string, CanMessageDefinition> updateData = new Dictionary<string, CanMessageDefinition>();
foreach (var record in dataDict)
{
    CanMessageDefinition recordValue = (CanMessageDefinition)record.Value;
    if (yourExistingRecord.KeyAttributes.Keys.Contains(record.Key) && (!yourExistingRecord.KeyAttributes.Values.Equals(record.Value)))
    { 
        updateData.Add(record.Key, recordValue);
    }
    
}
```

And just save your object to your db.

An alternative would be to do this inside a JsonConverter as you mentioned. Cheers